# More problems with "incomplete final line"

Tags: r

This problem is similar to that seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5990654/incomplete-final-line-warning-when-trying-to-read-a-csv-file-into-r).

I have a large number of large CSVs which I am loading and parsing serially through a function. Many of these CSVs present no problem, but there are several which are causing problems when I try to load them with `read.csv()`.

I have uploaded one of these files to a public Dropbox folder [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/83576/Candidate%20Mentions.csv) (note that the file is around 10.4MB).

When I try to read.csv() that file, I get the warning warning message:

```
In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
  incomplete final line found by readTableHeader on ...
```

And I cannot isolate the problem, despite scouring StackOverflow and Rhelp for solutions. Maddeningly, when I run

```
Import <- read.csv("http://dl.dropbox.com/u/83576/Candidate%20Mentions.csv")
```

using the Dropbox URL instead of my local path, it loads, but when I then save that very data frame and try to reload it thus:

```
write.csv(Import, "Test_File.csv", row.names = F)
TestImport <- read.csv("Test_File.csv")
```

I get the "incomplete final line" warning again.

**So, I am wondering why the Dropbox-loaded version works, while the local version does not, and how I can make my local versions work -- since I have somewhere around 400 of these files (and more every day), I can't use a solution that can't be automated in some way.**

In a related problem, perhaps deserving of its own question, it appears that some "special characters" break the `read.csv()` process, and prevent the loading of the entire file. For example, one CSV which has 14,760 rows only loads 3,264 rows. The 3,264th row includes this eloquent Tweet:

> "RT @akiron3: ácÎå23BkªÐÞ'q(@BarackObama )nÄ¤Ã¿ükTPPÂ ÍþnÄ¤üÈ’áY‹ªÐÞÄ¤Ã¿üŽ
>   \&’ŸõWˆFSnÄ¤©’FhÎåšBkêÕ„kÄ¤üÈLáUŒ~YÒhttp://t.co/ABNnWfTN
>   “jg)(WˆF"

Again, given the serialized loading of several hundred files, **how can I (a) identify what is causing this break in the `read.csv()` process, and (b) fix the problem with code, rather than by hand?**

Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Whatever the api you're using to scrape twitter, there is often a language parameter.  Maybe specify only tweets in English... or write some code (in R or otherwise) to remove all the craziness from that file.  I would start with `readLines` and go to the proverbial town from there.

Answer (score 3):

1)

```
 suppressWarnings(TestImport <- read.csv("Test_File.csv") )
```

2) Unmatched quotes are the most common cause of apparent premature closure. You could try adding all of these:

```
 quote="", na,strings="", comment.char=""
```