# Incomplete final line when trying to read csv in R

Tags: macos, r, excel, csv, end-of-line

I've got R v.2.15.1 running on Mac OS 10.8.2 . Earlier today, R started throwing errors at me every time I try to import ANY recently created (today) csv files. Older (before today) csv files work fine, but anything I create that's new will not read in without a warning.

I'm creating the csv's the same way -- saving the spreadsheet as .csv in MS Excel (Office for Mac 2011).

Even with a dummy file ('test.csv'), I get this: 
"Warning message:
In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
  incomplete final line found by readTableHeader on 'test.csv'"

in TextEdit, test.csv is:

```
cat,stuff
1,1
2,2
```

I have tried hitting enter at the end of every line (as suggested here: ['Incomplete final line' warning when trying to read a .csv file into R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5990654/incomplete-final-line-warning-when-trying-to-read-a-csv-file-into-r) ) , but this doesn't work.

I've re-installed R and Microsoft Excel. Weirdly, I was able to read in the csv file without a warning on a Windows machine with R. On another Mac with R and also with RStudio, I get the same warning...

I know this is "just" a warning, but it makes me a bit nervous and seems to have the potential to cause problems in the future.

Comment: This happens to me sporadically, and I have no idea why - it is a quirk of MS Excel, somehow not creating the .csv file correctly. Sometimes restarting Excel helps.

Comment: It will help if you can post an actual problem file, e.g. on Dropbox.

Comment: Actually, I'd be much more cautious. R doesn't tell you what it's importing, you have to tell it. I'd double check all your columns to ensure they match your expected type (int, numeric, character, factor). \

Comment: There has to be one blank line at the end. In your `test.csv`, hit enter after `2,2` once you open it in a text editor. hit save and do a `read.csv` on it. No errors, right?

Comment: Excel "helpfully" has varying defaults for the EOL character (nothing, CR/LF,  etc), so it can creat ".csv" files which are slightly different.  As DWin points out, it's just a warning, and will not cause problems

Answer (score 4):

There is no basis for worry. R's read functions are "expecting" to have an empty line but they are not resulting in malformed dataframes.

Comment: @Maiasuara , yes that actually seemed to work! if i did it in excel, it was still giving me issues, but if i do it in a text editor, it seems to work... guess i'll just be doing that before I read anything into R, just to be sure it's being read in correctly... Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this exact problem, and in my case, the data frame I got was malformed.  I found that saving an Excel file as UTF-16 and then invoking `read.table(... fileEncoding='UTF-16')` worked perfectly.  No processing required after exporting UTF file from Excel.