# Error when reading txt file

Tags: r

I saved a dataframe in notepad  named as ANOVA :

```
143 141 150 146 148
152 149 137 143 0
134 136 132 127 0
129 127 132 129 130
```

when I used `read.table()` command in R console ,that is,

```
> read.table("ANOVA.txt")
V1  V2  V3  V4  V5
1 143 141 150 146 148
2 152 149 137 143   0
3 134 136 132 127   0
4 129 127 132 129 130

Warning message:
In read.table("ANOVA.txt") :
incomplete final line found by readTableHeader on 'ANOVA.txt'
```

What is the reason of this warning massage? How can I prevent it?

again when I run the `apply()` command that

```
> apply("ANOVA.txt",2,sum)
Error in apply("ANOVA.txt", 2, sum) : dim(X) must have a positive length
```

Why this error occuring? How can i prevent it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here somebody had the same trouble, and got answered. Basically, the last line of your file doesn't end with a EOL character

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5996412/2123175

About the second question, the apply function doesn't work on files but variables, you need to read the table first. So, either use:

```
variable<-read.table("ANOVA.txt")

apply(variable,2,sum)
```

Or directly

```
apply(read.table("ANOVA.txt"),2,sum)
```