# R json,incomplete final line found

Tags: json, r

My problem: R json,incomplete final line found

My effort: I followed ['Incomplete final line' warning when trying to read a .csv file into R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5990654/incomplete-final-line-warning-when-trying-to-read-a-csv-file-into-r0)

I used this [site](http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/) to check my [file](http://www.filedropper.com/sunwayfb)s validity. It is data from my facebook news feed collected using graph api.

My code:

```
library("rjson")
work<-"C:/ContainingFolder/"
json_data <- fromJSON(paste(readLines(paste0(work,"SunwayFB.txt")), collapse=""))
```

My error:

```
Warning message:
In readLines(paste0(work, "SunwayFB.txt")) :
  incomplete final line found on 'C:/ContainingFolder/SunwayFB.txt'
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It works without any errors if you read the file with `fromJSON` instead of `readLines`.

```
fp <- file.path(work, "SunwayFB.txt")
json_data <- fromJSON(file = fp)
```

By the way: For the `readLines` way, you have to add a new line at the end of the file.

Answer (score 3):

You can ignore the warning message.

`readLines(paste0(work,"SunwayFB.txt"))`

add warn field.

`readLines(paste0(work,"SunwayFB.txt"), warn=FALSE)`

Answer (score 1):

In most cases, **Incomplete final line** warnings can be averted by appending a new line to the file you are trying to open. Just **go to the end of file -> press enter -> Save the file -> re-run whatever command you are using to load it in R** and it shall show no warning.