# Error Detecting Locale when deploying shiny

Tags: r, deployment, shiny, locale

When I try to deploy my shiny application, I go this error. I tried to setlocale but it didnt help. Why did I get this error, what should I do?

> Uploading bundle for document: 2646593...Detecting system locale ... Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) :
> Send failure: Connection was reset
> Calls:  ... tryCatch -> tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne -> 
> In addition: Warning message:
> Error detecting locale: Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote, : incomplete final line found by readTableHeader on 'raw'
> (Using default: en_US)
> Timing stopped at: 0.09 0.17 25.96
> Execution halted

Answer (score 0):

It's a little difficult to tell where you're deploying to or what the function error might be (is this to shinyappa.io? RStudio Connect?)

Have you tried look into the warning message? Addressing the `read.table` error might help, either the formatting of the file being uploaded could be throwing an error or your application may not be able to properly locate it after deployment.

Check out [this set of answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22171858/in-read-table-incomplete-final-line-found-by-readtableheader) to a similar `read.table` error.