# How to import single columned multiple observations data in SAS/R?

Tags: r, csv, sas

There is a given dummy dataset. I am trying to import it into the SAS environment and i also tried it in RStudio as well. But i was unable to grab the correct output. the dataset provided is as follows:

```
1    "name, age, salary, zipcode"
2    "A, 1, 100, 10010 B, 2, 200, 10011 C, 3, 300, 10012 D, 4, 400, 10014"
```

i copied the data from a CSV file. The line 1 was in the First cell of the CSV and Line 2 was in the second cell just below the first cell.

PS : 10010 is the zipcode where as B is the Name that is B is the starting of next observation and similiarly C is the next observation and D is the next observation.

The Desired output is:

```
Name   Age   Salary   Zipcode
 A      1     100      10010
 B      2     200      10011
 C      3     300      10012
 D      4     400      10014
```

i am stuck with this problem since a day ago. I am just able to move around the dataset in order to move the observations. Moreover the double qouted values are making this problem very complex. A working Solution on SAS or R would work great.

EDIT: The following code has been tried by me in SAS. Thanks SMW for pointing. :)

```
data new;
length Name $2 Age 8. Salary 8. Zipcode 8.;
infile 'book1.csv' dsd dlm = ',' firstobs = 2 LRECL =17 ;
input Name $ Age Salary Zipcode @@;
run;
```

Regards

Comment: Believe you need either the trailing "@" or you can use "\" to control what records go to what observation. Once you post an attempt of code I will know for sure, but not 100% certain of your question at this point.

Comment: @SMW Added the Edit in the query. Thanks much. Please let me know for any Catch in the code.

Comment: Does the file literally have the quotes?  Does it really have all of the data on the second line?  You could probably get SAS to read it by telling SAS that space, comma and quotes are delimiters `DLM=' ,"'`.  But if any of the values are blank or if the names have embedded spaces then it will get confused.

Comment: @Tom Yes the file literally have the quotes. and all the data is on the second line. But the space delimiter is at the end of each OBSERVATION. Not at every single value. That's the reason the above code didn't worked efficiently. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Import the column names and prepare it

```
nam <- read.table("csv.csv", header=F, nrow=1, stringsAsFactors=F)
nam <- gsub(",", "", nam)
nam <- nam[2]                             # resolve " " in original data 
nam <- strsplit(nam, split=" ")           #
```

Capitalize the colnames

```
library(Hmisc)                   # edited
nam <- capitalize(nam)           # edited
```

Import the remaining file

```
dd <- read.table("csv.csv", skip=1, sep="", stringsAsFactors=F)
```

Reorder the file, extract first column

```
col_1 <- gsub(",", "", as.vector(dd[seq(from=1, to=16,by=4)])[1,])
```

Extract the remaining columns

```
col_all <- as.data.frame(t(matrix(dd, ncol=4)))
```

Clean commas

```
col_all <- apply(apply(col_all[-1], 2, gsub, patt=",", replace=""), 2, as.numeric)
```

and set the final object

```
data <- as.data.frame(cbind(col_1, col_all))
names(data) <- nam
data  # ouput

  Name Age Salary Zipcode
1    A   1    100   10010
2    B   2    200   10011
3    C   3    300   10012
4    D   4    400   10014
```

**Edited:** Capitalize only with base functions. Avoid `library(Hmisc)`and the following code line.

```
nam <- unlist(lapply(nam, function(x) {                    
   paste(toupper(substring(x, 1, 1)), substring(x, 2, max(nchar(nam))), sep="")
}))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) But can it be done without using any external packages? i want to know if it could be done with standard available packages of RStudio.

Comment: Included a base version.

Comment: Warning message:
In read.table("C:/Users/Abhi Gupta/Desktop/file1.csv", skip = 1,  :
  incomplete final line found by readTableHeader on 'C:/Users/Abhi Gupta/Desktop/file1.csv'  Found this error in the console.

Comment: I think it isn't a problem associated with this question. Hope it helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5990654/incomplete-final-line-warning-when-trying-to-read-a-csv-file-into-r

Comment: Getting some more errors too:

1. Error in `[.data.frame`(dd, seq(from = 1, to = 16, by = 4)) : 
  undefined columns selected

2. > col_all <- apply(apply(col_all[-1], 2, gsub, patt=",", replace=""), 2, as.numeric)
Error in apply(apply(col_all[-1], 2, gsub, patt = ",", replace = ""),  : 
  dim(X) must have a positive length

Comment: can you indicate the result of `class (dd)` and `dim(dd)`? Then, have you used `as.vector (dd ...)`?

Comment: > class(dd)
[1] "data.frame"
> dim(dd)
[1] 1 1

@PereG here is the dimension

Comment: In your example, the dim(dd) must be 1 16, because read.table separated by whitespace. Check out your original file to see if it is. Only using a sample of your file could advance.

Comment: Try aditional argument in read.table()` task and a new clean task: `dd <- read.table("csv.csv", skip=1, sep="",stringsAsFactors=F, quote="")` and `dd <- gsub("[[:punct:]]", "", dd)`

Comment: The original file was imported directly and is not altered. I am not sure of what the error is about.

Comment: > col_1 <- gsub(",", "", as.vector(dd[seq(from=1, to=16,by=4)])[1,])
Error in as.vector(dd[seq(from = 1, to = 16, by = 4)])[1, ] : 
  incorrect number of dimensions

Comment: I use to=16 because the example dataset was. Replace with  `col_1 <- gsub(",", "", as.vector(dd[seq(from=1, to=length(dd),by=4)]))`

Answer (score 0):

You can ask SAS to treat comma, blank and quote as delimiters and use trail @@ to allow it to read multiple observations from one line.

Let's build your example data file.

```
filename example temp;
data _null_;
  file example;
  put '"name, age, salary, zipcode"'
    / '"A, 1, 100, 10010 B, 2, 200, 10011 C, 3, 300, 10012 D, 4, 400, 10014"'
 ;
run;
```

And now read it.

```
data want;
  length Name $2 Age 8. Salary 8. Zipcode 8.;
  infile example dlm = ' ,"' firstobs = 2 ;
  input Name $ Age Salary Zipcode @@;
run;
```

Comment: That's a perfect explanation. But what if the data is very large then we have to import the data into the SAS environment. If import function can be used in the solution then it could be a better explanation.

Comment: Thanks so much @Tom this logic worked perfectly with import command too. the main logic was to identify various delimiters in the given data. Thanks a ton mate.

Comment: what if the dataset contains the missing values? for instance let me provide you with a dataset

"name, age, salary, zipcode"
"A, 1, 100,  B, 2, 200, 10011 C, 3, 300, 10012 , 4, 400, 10014 E, 5, , 10015"

Comment: It will not work if the missing values are represented by spaces. If the missing values are represented by a `.` then it will work.

Comment: If you want to use PROC IMPORT to convert your files than you need to make sure that they are in a cleaner format. I would go back to source and find out why the values got quoted as if they were a single string and why the end of line characters between the data rows are missing.

Comment: Thanks much @Tom it was of great help.