# read.table quits after encountering special symbol

Tags: r, read.table

I am trying to read.table for a tab-delimited file using the following command:

```
df <- read.table("input.txt", header=FALSE, sep="\t", quote="", comment.char="", 
                 encoding="utf-8")
```

There should be `30 million` rows. However, after read.table() returns, df contains only ~6 million rows. And there is a warning message like this:

Warning message:

```
In read.table("input.txt", header = FALSE, sep = "\t", quote = "",  :
  incomplete final line found by readTableHeader on 'input.txt'
```

I believe `read.table` quits after encountering a special sympbol `(ASCII code: 1A Substitute)` in one of the string columns. In the input file, the only special character is tab because it is used to separate columns. Is there anyway to ask read.table to treat any other character as not special?

Comment: What is the character? Can you add a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/1217536) for people to work with?

Answer (score 0):

If you have 30 million rows. I would use `fread` rather than read.table. It is faster. Learn more about here  http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/data.table/docs/fread

```
 fread(input, sep="auto", encoding = "UTF-8" )
```

Regarding your issue with read.table. I think the solutions here should solve it.
['Incomplete final line' warning when trying to read a .csv file into R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5990654/incomplete-final-line-warning-when-trying-to-read-a-csv-file-into-r)