# r read json files incomplete final line found on

Tags: json, r

I would like to read a json file where the sutructure is like below. I tried fromJson but it just read the first block.  Can you help me on specify the delimiter to read all the file?

Thank you so much

```
json_data <- fromJSON(paste(readLines("C:C:/Users/aa/Data-test.json"), collapse=""))
```

> Warning message:
>       In readLines("C:/Users/aa/Data-test.json") :
>         incomplete final line found on 'C:/Users/jsalim/Desktop/Docapost_20160718/FILES/Extract-Morgane_1307/Data-device2.json'

```
{
  "id" : "aaa",
  "dateModification" : "2016-06-04T04:29:30Z",
  "active" : true,
.....
}
{
  "id" : "bbbb",
  "dateModification" : "2016-06-04T04:29:30Z",
  "active" : true,
.....
}
{
  "id" : "ccc",
  "dateModification" : "2016-06-04T04:29:30Z",
  "active" : true,
.....
}
```

Comment: I don't have the datas line per line but block per block, when a block ended a new one start to the next line but readline is n't ablkle to find an EOL

Comment: `?jsonlite::stream_in`

Comment: When I try using stream_in  it doexn't work , I also get the error opening file input connection.
Error: parse error: premature EOF
                                       {
                     (right here) ------^
closing file input connection.

Comment: if we had real test data someone wld prbly post a helpful working example. if you looked at `stream_in()` you'd see that i requires each streaming json record to be on a single line. possibly might have to use `jq` (the cmdline util) or `jqr` then (perhap in combo w/`jsonlite`)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that as in the answer suggested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5990654/incomplete-final-line-warning-when-trying-to-read-a-csv-file-into-r), you just need to enter a carriage return at the end of the line (that is, there should be a single empty line at the end of your file).  This worked for me in the same scenario.