# Import csv file with arabic characters using R

Tags: r, csv, encoding

I am trying to import a csv file containing arabic characters.

I used this command

```
data=read.csv("C:/Users/AHMED/Desktop/emploisaaa.csv",sep = ";")
```

it didn't work , the data looks like this

> ÎáíÉ ÇáÓáÇãÉ æÇáÕíÇäÉ Å ã ááã

when I added `fileEncoding='UTF-8'` I get this
warnig messages:

> 1: In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote =
>   quote,  :   entrée incorrecte trouvée dans la connexion en entrée
>   'C:/Users/AHMED/Desktop/emploisaaa.csv' 2: In read.table(file = file,
>   header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :   incomplete final line
>   found by readTableHeader on 'C:/Users/AHMED/Desktop/emploisaaa.csv'

Comment: Sounds like there's a problem with the final line being incomplete. (I'm skipping the first error message in French but it's probably similar.) [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5990654/incomplete-final-line-warning-when-trying-to-read-a-csv-file-into-r) may be relevant.

Comment: It's difficult to say without knowing more about the data set. What happens if you try to import via `read.delim` instead of `read.csv`?

Answer (score -1):

Here is what I did. The answer seems to come out in UTF.
[image]Display in R Gui of a table with two columns