# Error in read.zoo(tmp, header = TRUE, sep = ",") : index has bad entries at data rows: 1 2

Tags: r, xts, zoo, line-endings

I'm querying data from alphavantage using the `getSymbols.av` function.
Whenever I run the standalone paragraph

```
GOOGL <- getSymbols.av("GOOGL",auto.assign=F,return.class = "xts",adjusted=T,outputs.size="full",data.type="csv",periodicity = "weekly")
GOOG <- getSymbols.av("GOOG",auto.assign=F,return.class = "xts",adjusted=T,outputs.size="full",data.type="csv",periodicity = "weekly")
google <- rbind.xts(GOOGL["2013-05-17/2014-04-04"],GOOG["2013-05-17/2018-05-18"])
google <- google[-48,]
```

it works. However, when I try to run the whole script in Source mode, i get this error:

```
Error in read.zoo(tmp, header = TRUE, sep = ",") : 
  index has bad entries at data rows: 1 2
In addition: Warning message:
In read(file, ...) :
  incomplete final line found by readTableHeader on 'C:\Users\..\Temp
```

I opened that file and it is empty.

None of the other functions, who look exactly the same have this error.
I tried to get wiser by studying this answer:['Incomplete final line' warning when trying to read a .csv file into R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5990654/incomplete-final-line-warning-when-trying-to-read-a-csv-file-into-r) , but I didn't.

I'm a beginner at R, the code is meant to be sent to my Finance professor and I don't want to look like I'm struggling. I'd be very thankful for any help you could give.

My sessionInfo() is:

`R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)`

`Matrix products: default`

`locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252

[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C

[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252`

Comment: I cannot replicate this behavior using quantmod 0.4.13 in R-3.4.3 on 64-bit Ubuntu.  What is your `sessionInfo()` output (please edit it into your question)? Does it work if you do not set `data.type`?  Also, you should not call `getSymbols.av` directly.  Call `getSymbols("GOOGL", src = "av", ...)` instead.

Comment: when I remove data.type="csv", I can still not run the whole script.
If I only run the paragraph, it works however.

Does alphavantage have a strict time limit on API queries?

Comment: They probably have a limit, but two queries shouldn't be a problem.