# Error detecting locale with shinyapps.io

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to deploy an application shiny that works well locally using shinyapps.io. I have got the following error:

> Error detecting locale: Error in read.table(file = file, header =
>   header, sep = sep, quote = quote, : incomplete final line found by
>   readTableHeader on 'raw'  (Using default: en_US)

My sessionInfo() is as follow:

> R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21) Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
>   Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)
>
> Matrix products: default
>
> locale: [1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
>   LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United
>   States.1252 [4] LC_NUMERIC=C
>   LC_TIME=English_United States.1252

Locally I used Rstudio which is set in English, it is installed on Windows which is set in French, I don't know if this is relevant but it seems to be an encoding issue.

Any idea?

Thanks,

T.

Comment: have you tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5990654/incomplete-final-line-warning-when-trying-to-read-a-csv-file-into-r?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Strange thing is, I am not using any csv or read.table in my script. Perhaps DT package does?

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem when i putted the ui and server functions together in the same app.R script.

so the solution is:

- make sure you have the 3 separate files: **ui.R** ,**server.R** and **app.R** with the exact file names.
- don't forget to import the necessary packages at the beginning of each script.

the warning remained for me but the application was successfully deployed.