# incomplete final line found by readTableHeader in R

Tags: r, dataframe

i load data

```
read.table("path.txt", sep = "\t", header=TRUE, fileEncoding="UCS-2")
```

it contains three rows

```
x         x2
MAKFA   МАКФА
makar   макароны
макар.  макароны
```

but i get the warning

```
incomplete final line found by readTableHeader on
```

and as output my dataset (real incomplete)

```
      x x2
1 MAKFA МА
```

how to fix this problem (i need work only with .txt)

```
structure(list(x = structure(1L, .Label = "MAKFA", class = "factor"), 
               x2 = structure(1L, .Label = "МА", class = "factor")), .Names = c("x", 
                                                                                "x2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -1L))
```

solutuion here
['Incomplete final line' warning when trying to read a .csv file into R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5990654/incomplete-final-line-warning-when-trying-to-read-a-csv-file-into-r)
doesn't work

## here the link to download txt file

https://dropmefiles.com/FfcC6

Comment: to help deal with encoding issues it may be necessary to provide a link that enables downloading of the original file (browsers tend to coalesce everything to UTF-8 in the majority of locales)

Comment: @hrbrmstr, i updated post

Comment: (in the middle of something else but a quick look with the Unix `file` command shows: `23.txt: Little-endian UTF-16 Unicode text, with CRLF line terminators`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be optimal, but it works. `stringi`'s reliance on the ICU libraries makes it a great Swiss Army knife for overcoming encoding issues. When I saw that `vim` could read the file appropriately, I decided to give it a go with `stringi`:

```
library(stringi)
library(docxtractr)

stri_read_lines("23.txt") %>% 
  stri_split_fixed("\t", simplify = TRUE) %>% 
  as.data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE) %>% 
  docxtractr::assign_colnames(1)
##      old      new
## 1  MAKFA    МАКФА
## 2  makar макароны
## 3 макар. макароны
```